# Wait for a function to finish to load on Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am loading a function that translate many sentences in App.xlm.cs then after  charge my MainPage.

The problem is my function does not finish to load and MainPage is displayed.

How can I make sure that my function will be loaded?

Here is my function in App.Xml.cs:

```
public async void SetLeafLanguage() // here is the function I would like to wait before display the MainPage
{
        var phoneLanguage = "fr";// CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;

        // transversal
        var WarningConnexionText = await MicosoftTranslater.TranslateText("this the first text", phoneLanguage);

        // Test page 
        var NumberOfWords = await MicosoftTranslater.TranslateText("this the second text", phoneLanguage);


        var ExerciceTitle = await MicosoftTranslater.TranslateText("this the second text", phoneLanguage);

        var AnswerPlaceHolder = await MicosoftTranslater.TranslateText("this the second text", phoneLanguage);

        var LabelNumberOfWordToTranslate = await MicosoftTranslater.TranslateText("this the second text", phoneLanguage);

        // parameter labels
        var AboutUstext = await MicosoftTranslater.TranslateText("this the second text", phoneLanguage);

}

public void  GetUserOnData()
{
    SetLeafLanguage();
    MainPage = new MainPage();
}

public App ()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    GetUserOnData();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the return type of the method to be `Task` instead of `void`.

You should always avoid `async void` methods. See Microsoft's [Async/Await - Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming)

Change your code to be like this:

```cs
public async Task SetLeafLanguage() // here is the function I would like to wait before display the MainPage
{
        var phoneLanguage = "fr";// CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;

        // transversal
        var WarningConnexionText = await MicosoftTranslater.TranslateText("this the first text", phoneLanguage);

        // Test page 
        var NumberOfWords = await MicosoftTranslater.TranslateText("this the second text", phoneLanguage);


        var ExerciceTitle = await MicosoftTranslater.TranslateText("this the second text", phoneLanguage);

        var AnswerPlaceHolder = await MicosoftTranslater.TranslateText("this the second text", phoneLanguage);

        var LabelNumberOfWordToTranslate = await MicosoftTranslater.TranslateText("this the second text", phoneLanguage);

        // parameter labels
        var AboutUstext = await MicosoftTranslater.TranslateText("this the second text", phoneLanguage);

}

public async Task GetUserOnData()
{
    await SetLeafLanguage();
    MainPage = new MainPage();
}

public App ()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    GetUserOnData();
}
```

The difference is that now both methods `SetLeafLanguage` & `GetUserOnData` are of type `async Task`. This means that you can simply `await` SetLeafLanguage method. When you `await` it, this means that you will wait for the method to return something and then you can be sure that it has finished processing.

You can read more about the async return types here - [Async Return Types (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types)

Comment: What is the issue now?

Comment: some await in "SetLeafLanguage" are not finished , is there a wait to launch all await at same time ?

Comment: Yes, you could use Task.WaitAll() on all of the tasks. It accepts an array of tasks and waits them all.